# Bootstrap 3 application IE 9 rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I've developed an application with the following UI Stack

- Jquery 2.0.3
- Bootstrap 3
- Highcharts
- Jquery UI 1.10.3

No HTML 5 elements used.

Browsers on which app was successfully tested:

- Chrome 31.0
- Firefox 25.0
- IE 10 and 11

But I've run into major rendering issues on IE9, despite it being supported by Bootstrap 3.

When I first render the application, there's no error but none of the elements display at all.

The moment I open up the Developer tools console tab(to check errors) and do a fresh request, the whole application renders completely.

In the Developer tools on IE9, the Browser mode is IE9 and Document mode is IE9 Standards.

I even tried adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> to my HTML, but to no success.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Where's your code? -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't have a specific code to show you. I'm using Tiles with Spring MVC to populate my standard template..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a console.log wrapper http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/

Or use something like grunt-remove-logging https://github.com/ehynds/grunt-remove-logging to avoid similar accidents

Answer (score 0):

Found "console is undefined" on enabling debugger.

Same solution as accepted in this question [Console is undefined error in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183440/console-is-undefined-error-in-ie9)