# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, svelte

When trying to send message from content script to application im recieving this error and im not sure why. the content script is set up correctly as well as my manifest and file structure. i will put the code down below.

content script:

```js
window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async() => {
  const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    greeting: "hello"
  });
  console.log(response);
})
```

App.svelte:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(
  request,
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  if (request.greeting === "hello") sendResponse({
    farewell: "goodbye"
  });
});

manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Sveltechron",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Browser devtools extension for debugging Svelte applications.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
      "js": ["isolated.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "resources": ["svelte-listener/src/", "svelte-listener/src/index.js", "svelte-listener/src/listener.js", "svelte-listener/src/profiler.js", "svelte-listener/src/svelte.js"]
  }],
  "background": {
    "type": "module",
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "run_at": "document_start"
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "32": "images/32.png",
    "48": "images/48.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "background"]
}
```

im expecting the browser console to log the farewell message but im instead getting this error.

Comment: that implies `chrome.runtime` is undefined - perhaps your content script and/or manifest isn't "setup correctly" after all

Comment: `"world": "MAIN"` in manifest.json might be the problem. Try remove it and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @hackape i tried that and didnt work

Comment: @JaromandaX i believe i have everything in the manifest for it to work. would you mind helping me further?

Comment: No idea, looks OK

Comment: though, why not use `"js": ["content.js", "isolated.js"],` since both scripts have the same "matches" and "run_at" values

Comment: Could be a [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251624/3617380). No idea. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: I can only suggest reduce your setup to the bare minimum. Start over from scratch, add only the manifest.json and content.js with just one line `console.log(chrome.runtime.sendMessage)`. I guess it would work at this point. Then you add code back into this setup, bit by bit toward your current state, and see at what point it breaks.

Comment: Or you can go the other way around, remove code from your current codebase to see at which point it starts working.

Comment: The problem is `world: MAIN` because it runs the scripts in the page context and not in the default context where `chrome` is defined. You probably forgot to reload the extension when you tested without world. The solution is to use `chrome` in isolated.js and communicate via CustomEvent between content.js and isolated.js.